# Error in creating custome module in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I am new in magento i want to create a Hello World Module i am follow many tutorial but i am always getting 404 error

My app/etc/module file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Quinchy_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Quinchy_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My Php clas file in app/local/Quinchy/Demo
which is

```
<?php

class Quinchy_Demo_Model_Hotel extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello Quinchy";
    }
}
?>
```

and config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Quinchy_Demo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Quinchy_Demo>
    </modules>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quinchy>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Quinchy_Demo</module>
                    <frontName>quinchy</frontName>
                </args>
            </quinchy>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

and i calling this Module using this URL

```
127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/quinchy,
127.0.0.1/magento/quinchy/
127.0.0.1/magento/quinchy/index
```

File Structure 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMb5I.png)
please help me

Comment: Aside from the answers below, you need to make sure that your XML configuration is all absolutely correct (capital letters, file names) - so best to post your filenames as well as half of their paths and contents

Answer (score 0):

Your "model" should actually be a controller, which is the type of class that serves content to the frontend or adminhtml areas. Models are for dealing with data.

Try this for your controller:

```
# File: app/code/local/Quinchy/Demo/controllers/HotelController.php
<?php

class Quinchy_Demo_HotelController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello Quinchy";
        exit;
    }
}
```

BTW, you'd access this via `/magento/quinchy/hotel/index`

Comment: Your code is in app/code/local/ rather than app/local as your question states?

Comment: yes my code is in app/code/local/Quinchy/Demo/controllers

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be in the 'app/local/Quinchy/Demo/controllers/IndexController.php' file. And the class name should be 'Quinchy_Demo_IndexController' (`class Quinchy_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`).

Your extension should look like this:
`app/etc/modules/Quinchy_Demo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Quinchy_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Quinchy_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Quinchy/Demo/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config>
    <modules>
        <Quinchy_Demo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Quinchy_Demo>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <quinchy>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Quinchy_Demo</module>
                    <frontName>quinchy</frontName>
                </args>
            </quinchy>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Quinchy/Demo/controllers/IndexController.php`:

```
<?php
class Quinchy_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello Quinchy";
    }
}
```